# Microsoft teams apps openbadges Bot Application not working

Tags: reactjs, botframework, c#-2.0

I have configure all prerequisite for microsoft teams apps openbadges bot application in visual studio 2019 with .net core 2.1 version(installed .net core 2.1 sdk as per project requirement) after that I run project and test api from postman but app didn't work
project doc: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-openbadges
any suggestion on that